# How to set LANG in locale, despite it's in /etc/default/locale in ubuntu for unicode support?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, emacs, locale, unicode

I run `Ubuntu 12.04`, I can't set the locale to `en_US.utf8`. I set the `LANG` by configuring `/etc/default/locale` as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale#List_installed_locales).

```
$cat /etc/default/locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
$locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=POSIX
```

But it doesn't work, as you can see above. How do I set this `LANG` variable to `en_US.utf8`?

The reason I am asking is, when I run `echo -e "\x03\bb"`, I get a `unicode greek letter lambda symbol` displayed correctly, but my issue is with emacs. In the emacs, I can't display unicode symbols, eg: `C-x 8 RET 03bb` outputs `\u03bb`, instead of a `greek letter lambda symbol`. I thought the issue is with these locale settings, but I can't set them.

**Edit**:
I think the problem is fixed.

```
$su $USER -c 'env; echo ==; locale' | egrep '==|LANG'

LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=en_US
==
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=en_US
```

The solution for me was, I was using mintty to ssh into `Ubuntu 12.04
Server Edition`, so I had to configure `~/.pam_environment` and
`~/.etc/ssh_config`, and `~/bashrc`. But my real issue with emacs was
not about this ubuntu configuration, so I have no idea what this
`LANG` variable configuration is used for or if I set it to correct values.

**Edit 2:**
Here are the steps I've taken to solve this, following the suggestions
of ansivirus from the #ubuntu irc channel:

Add this to `~/.bash_profile`

```
export LANGUAGE="en"
export LANG="C"
export LC_MESSAGES="C"
```

Add this to `~/.pam_environment` (so this must be problematic)

```
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=en_US
```

Add this to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
UsePAM yes
```

Comment out this in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
#   SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Comment: What is the output of `su $USER -c 'env; echo ==; locale' | egrep '==|LANG'`? Are you using the default GUI environment (Unity), if not what are you using, and what display manager?

Comment: Is `LANG` present when you run `su` but not when you log in over SSH then? What did you change? Note that `en_US` is not a Unicode locale.

Comment: @Gilles, see my edit2 please. After taking those steps now LANG is kind of present I think, but I don't know what affect it has, and I don't care because emacs is fixed and I can see the unicode characters fine, I would appreciate an explanation of what these variables mean and what they affect though, thanks.

Comment: Also note that these didn't fix my emacs problem, it was an emacs issue after all.

Comment: Maybe related to: The correct spelling for the locale is AFAIK en_US.UTF-8, not .utf8

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall `locales`

```
apt-get install --reinstall locales
```

Read more [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151104171609/http://linux-ubuntu.info:80/en/how-to-change-the-default-locale/).